# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stopPropagation' of undefined for modified dropdown

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, dropdown

I have modified the dropdown menu of bootstrap to make it a small menu type form.

Since by default when you click on the dropdown it disappears.
So I have used e.stopPropagation() to prevent it from hiding.

It is working fine for me in several place except for one place where the code is exactly same.

```
                edit_charges = '<button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" style="border:none;background:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer;float:right">' \
                           '<i class="fa fa-pen"></i>' \
                           '<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-extra">' \
                           '<label>Extra Charges</label>' \
                           '<input type="number" min="0" class="form-control form-control-sm extra_charges" placeholder="Amount" style="margin-bottom:5px" />' \
                           '<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block" onclick="edit_extra_charges($(this))" value="Save"/>' \
                           '</ul>' \
                           '</button>'
```

And for handling it.

```
        $('.dropdown-menu-extra').on('click', function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        $('.dropdown-menu-extra').on('keyup', function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 32) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        });
```

My menu look like this.

[image]

Now when I click on thee dropdown, it doesn't disappears which is correct, it means `e.stopPropagation();` is working fine but when i click on the save button it shows me this error:

[image]

P.S: It is working fine with the same set code at severals places.

Thank you!